# Date value converted from Calendar outputs different format than String

Tags: java, spring, date, java-calendar

This is the code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(dateFormat.parse("2019-03-06 10:54:06 AM"));
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);

    System.out.println("String Format: " + dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
    System.out.println("Date Format: " + dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime())));
```

The result is:

```
String Format: 2019-03-06 04:54:06 PM
Date Format: Wed Mar 06 16:54:06 BDT 2019
```

But the expected result is:

```
String Format: 2019-03-06 04:54:06 PM
Date Format: 2019-03-06 04:54:06 PM
```

Can you please tell my how to to that?

Comment: We are in **2019**, so please use the "new" `java.time` api introduced in **2014** with Java 8, and not this old broken mess

Comment: You are asking the impossible. A `Date` hasn’t got (as in cannot have) a format. And 100 % what @Lino said so well. [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.